# Background template in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Just wondering if it is possiable to have a website in the background of tinyMCE?

The effect I am after is so the user can see the whole website when editing a page, but can only edit text in a specified area of the site design.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do here is include an edit button, or what have you, that only shows if they're a valid logged in user. This could be from the backend or the front end, but you'd have to figure out who you want to access edit levels on the page.

Then you can reload the page and have the TinyMCE instance sitting right where the content would be.

[image: example tinymce overlay]

Then they'd edit and save the page and it would return them back to the non-edit version.

You get both the design of the actual page in the background and you can lock them down to editing only that portion of the page where you specify and place TinyMCE.